Koin Activitity scoped injection via koinViewModel()
I am using a single app activity with jetpack compose and and using koinViewModel() (koin 4.0.0) to inject the ViewModel for the compose screens like so:
@Composable
fun LoggedInScreen(viewModel: LoggedInViewModel = koinViewModel()) {
   val state = viewModel.model.collectAsState()
   WebViewWrapper(state.value, viewModel)
}

So koinViewModel() only seems to be able to see the global scope. Since i have module scoped for my MainActivity:
val module = module {
    scope<MainActivity> {
       viewModel {
             MainViewModel(
                  state = State(),
                  authRepository = get(),
                  emailLoginFlow = get(),
                  appleLoginFlow = get(),
                  networkWatcher = get(),
                  mapper = get(),
                  settings = get(),
             )
        }
        scoped<Activity>{get<MainActivity>()}
        // .. more activity scoped deps ....
}

I have tried to pass in the scope from the activity down via compose and call koinViewModel(scope) but the scoped dependencies are never found.
Wondering if someone can suggest the right/good way to inject scoped dependencies using koinViewModel() (at the moment I'm keeping an activity singleton with global factory methods but this is obviously bad)

This is by design, why do you even want anything Activity-scoped in a ViewModel?
